# PHP short tags not working as expected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make my php page working, by having html code combined with it. Here is a source code:

```
<?

$username="username";
$password="password";
$db_name="db_name";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$userstable='profile';
$query = "SELECT * FROM $userstable order by id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>DayZSC | Showlist</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

    <div id="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </div>

    <?
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

    <div class='p_content'>
    <h3>
    <?
    echo ".$row['name'].";
    ?>
    </h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
    <table align="center"><tbody><tr>
    <td>Copies Sold (Week)</td>
    <td>11152</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Copies pirated (Week)</td>
    <td>124214</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </p>
    <h2><a href="#">Comments</a></h2><br /><br />
    </div>

    <?
    }
    ?>

    <div id="footer">All rights reserved &copy 2014 | Designed by <a href="http://berdyevcreations.com" target="_blank" style="color: #000;">BerdyevCreations</a></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So whenever I try to run this page, it gives me just a blank. Cannot find error log either. Please help?

Comment: is short tag enabled if not use <?php // ur code ?>

Comment: Short open tags? Try using `<?php` rather than `<?`

Comment: Please start with something simple.  Does `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` work?

Comment: @OliCharleswort 

Yes it does.

Comment: @berdyev: Ok, well start building up the complexity incrementally, rather than starting with something complex and being stumped when it doesn't work at all.  Also, check the page in the "view source" view that your browser offers, there may be some clues there.

Comment: Obligatory suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth 

Why would I do that? I'm just trying to re-design my pages, by adding better design, but it doesn't work. I'm here to get a solution, not a advice.

Comment: this is not going to work `echo ".$row['name'].";`

Comment: do you see any html on view page source?

Comment: Why and how do I fix it? @LozCherone

Comment: @berdyev: SO is not a "fix my code" service; you should adhere to good development/debug practices in the first instance.  Once you've identified the core problem, then we can help you fix it.

Comment: just try: `<?= $row['name'] ?>`

Comment: You're not helping at all. I feel like you're just trying to be a smartass here. @OliCharlesworth

Comment: Then good luck with your problem.

Comment: I think @MattClark spotted the issue, did you try it?

Comment: Yes it did work! Weird thing. Can anybody explain me how does that work? @CodeBird

Comment: @berdyev pro tip-spell check your web site.

Comment: well normally the `.` is for concatenating strings, you were putting a double quote then a `.` that's wrong for php

Comment: and your &copy in the html footer needs a ; at the end for it to work or it will just show `&copy` :) @berdyev

Comment: Hi @berdyev, I just added my comment as an actual answer because you say that it helped you. Good luck, and happy coding! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the PHP short tags wring, try and use this:

```
<?= $row['name'] ?>
```

Instead of your

```
<?
echo ".$row['name'].";
?
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :D Any more question, please feel free to ask.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problems is with `php tags`, you are curently using short ones while your php is probably not configured to accept them so change short tags

```
<?
```

To long tags

```
<?php
```

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. I have some simple php pages, with short tags and it does work properly. Even though I tried to add long tags, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the short code directive in `PHP.INI` if you have php version 5.3 and earlier

since 5.4 This directive is enabled by default

like this 
`php.ini`

`short_open_tag=On`

Comment: The OP has short tags enabled, however, he was using them incorrectly.